Indian passport holders applying to both Australian and NZ visa (from India)
I am planning a family visit to both countries. Going through the official websites, it seems that booking flights before visa issuance is not a great idea (both sites clearly mention it). So can I apply for both visas in parallel?
My main concern earlier was that since my flights into and out of the region would be in Australia (Melbourne), would NZ wait for me to get my Australian visa first? This of course is driven by my travels to Europe where a return flight ticket is a necessity before applying for the Schengen visa.
Kindly let me know if I can start both processes in parallel.

The accepted approach is to apply for visas in reverse order, starting with the final destination. Australia will want to know that you have the correct paperwork to enter NZ. NZ is unlikely to care where you’re arriving from.

As a rule of thumb, countries do not care about other countries' visas, whether you can enter New Zealand is not Australia's concern and vice versa.  So yes, you can apply for the visas in parallel.
However, for your specific itinerary, you will likely need a multiple entry visa for Australia since you will need to leave it for NZ and re-enter on your way back.  If so, you should get the NZ visa first and attach the granted visa to your application to demonstrate that the itinerary is possible.  (If you're doing an airside transit one-way, which does not require  a visa, this is not a concern.)
Finally, countries do care about visa denials at other countries, since that's a signal that there's something risky/untrustworthy about you. Australia and NZ in particular cooperate closely, so if you're denied a visa by one, this will likely complicate getting a visa from the other.

thanks .. the multiple entry visa thing totally skipped my mind ..appreciate it
